# XSLT to output XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Lately I have been amazed at the wondrous powers of XSLT. One of the things I have found the most intriguing was about using XSLT to process other XSLT documents to generate dynamic templates. Although I can imagine how easily this can be done using raw text output to produce the necessary XSL tags in the output (e.g., `<![CDATA[<xsl:value-of="" />]]>`), since the XSLT is by definition an XML document there sure is a way of producing a valid XSLT output as an XML tree. How can this be done, if at all, without confusing the XSLT parser (as both the input template AND the output would live in the same namespace)?

Comment: Read on xsl:namespace-alias

Comment: An example of using XSLT to generate another XSLT stylesheet can be found in the XSLT specification itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#element-namespace-alias

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pawel for his insight into `xsl:namespace-alias`. I didn't seem to hit the right keywords on a search engine. For anyone interested in a working solution, an example could be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias">

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <axsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
        <axsl:template match="/">
            <axsl:value-of select="'Some text'" />
        </axsl:template>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which would result in the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Some text'" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you take a look at http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus that is exactly how it works. It uses xslt to convert xml derived from html and css to xslt for xsl fo.